# Nested VPN over networked VMs -for the pros

Tags: nested, virtual-machine, vpn

I need help with this and hoping someone can answer with a valid suggestion.

Background: I live under potential threats from nefarious entities and need some help with security.

My setup is this (similar)
Internet dropping into a WinXP VM by NAT from the Win7 host (call the first VM "VM1").  Connecting within VM1 to a VPN.  This TAP adapter internet connection is then shared with a local network of VMs (VM2 and VM3) connected by a network adapter #2 on a Lan Segment I created.

The other VMs are private.  I work from them.

I connect another VPN from within them, tunneling through the VM1 effectively nesting them.

However-

Recently some reasons for concern.  I am very concerned now that someone with ill intent could be accessing my VM1 through either the host system internet connection, or directly into it from the first VPN, and could be traversing my little Lan Segment network and accessing the data on the lan segment VM2 or VM3 directly.  Copying data off potentially into VM1 for removal, -or other threats.

I recently have had my USB wifi adapter disconnect from the host and connect itself mysteriously directly to my deep VMs, 2 and 3.  It's happened several times-  I now removed USB controller from both of those internal VMs as a precaution.  Apparently they wanted to bypass all of my security and just cause the internal deep VMs to connect directly to my wifi and report back the info..

So..

what I need help on, is how to keep the lan segment truly private, with ONLY the VPN internet traffic capable of going through the segment to my upper VM1.

For consideration: 
Are there windows services that should be stopped or removed from within VM2 or 3 Which in particular pose threats?

RDP off in the registry for example?

how to disable all communication between the deep VMs and VM1 except for the passing through of the internet connection and nested VPN?

Would I start in the TCP/IP stack? removing some of it?  Do I need PFSense or another firewall VM inbetween the lan segment and VM1?

Please help me secure my operating VMs from which I work.  Let's call me a journalist under an oppresive regime hypothetically and I am very concerned for my safety, but cannot abandon my moral obligations and work.

Answer (score 1):

great question albeit a bit lengthy and panicked sounding.  I can't know your 'situation' but I'll try to help.  First, relax.  Second, put PFSense in between your deep VMs and where your internet drops into your machine.  Keep your internet dropping into your VM if possible through the use of Xen and PCIe passthrough. Just pass the network card along into your first upper VM, so any attackers would have to escape that and into the host in order to infect it.  Try and keep a clean host.  Second, image your upper VM where the internet hits and reload it fresh every day.  Just copy it over from a USB or such. Prevent persistant threats-

Next, keep an isolated network between your VM1 (upper) and a PFsense VM.  Then connect another adapter to PFSense and an isolated network with your "deep VMs".  Delete them regularly. Keeping things fresh is one of the keys to avoiding threats and malwares etc.

Hope this helps, and best of luck wherever you may be. 
**Use encryption in everything.